Extreme points of the set of $\varphi$-invariant probability measaures, where $\varphi(z) = z^2, |z| = 1$
Is it true that the closed (in the weak-star topology) convex hull of $\varphi$-invariant probability measures with the supports on orbits of $\varphi$-periodic points coincides with the set of all $\varphi$-invariant probability measures?

I believe those are exactly the extreme points of the set? If so, this just follows from Krein-Milman.

Yes, but how to prove that these are the only extreme points?
